# Incorporating Signal R into an already existing web application

Tags: c#, rest, http, websocket, signalr

From my understanding, the beauty of signal R is that it takes care of the "handshake" between the client and server to determine the best form of communciation between them (websockets, long polling, etc). I understand that by default it does this at the /signalr route. I read that before this the handshake would be accomplished with an HTTP Get request with an Upgrade/Connection header specifying to upgrade to this new connection.

In my current application we support handling many HTTP requests in a RESTful manner. If we wanted to expose some of this data in real time rather than in this request response format, what would be the best way to determine if we should open a connection using signal R? Would checking for those headers still suffice? I just feel like that is a bit redundant since signal R abstracts that away.

Instead of this, would a solution be for the client to specifically invoke a hub method to kick off the streaming as soon as he connects to the proper endpoint?

TLDR: Need a way to open a signal R connection from a HTTP request, don't know the best way to go about that whether it be from requesting the resource with custom HTTP headers or by just navigating to the url resource and having their client invoke a hub method.

Comment: from my understanding, signalr allows the Server side to call the client side function, which can't be done using http request/response.

Comment: There might be a misunderstanding: The server is not the one initiating the connection, this is the client's part.

Answer (score 1):

A typical example of using signalr is:

1. an html file using JavaScript to connect to a signalr Server when the page is loaded.  we call this signalr client.
2. a signalr server written in c#.  it can be a winform or console or service.
3. the signalr Server can call any dll, or webservices or webapi located in the same server, or even in different Server.

then, the client can call any function defined in the signalr server.  the server can call any function defined in the client for a particular client or for groups of clients.

also, client x can call client y functions as well.

I would also suggest you create this index.html inside a Cordova project, so that your client can use this app using any pc desktop browser, or any mobile phone browser, or run it as an Android or iPhone native app, by using One set of client codes.

Comment: Doesn't answer the question on the best practice to use signal r in an existing project where the client code is unknown and they are interacting with the service via http requests

Comment: what technology are you using in your client, html or aspx or php or winform?

Comment: That is the kicker. We don't know what technology the client will use we want to just specify the url route they would normally just send a http request too, but we will tell them the hub methods they need to have implementations for. So instead of normally sending a http request to get a piece of information we want to open a socket connection using signal r

Comment: First of all, I would assume that you want to ask the client to do something Before the client send a request, otherwise you don't need to use signalr.  e.g. to display the stock market information in real time.  In this case, the client need to create a function for the signalr Server to call.  and you should Standardize this client function by providing sample codes to your client.

Comment: however, signalr is not suitable for all kinds of client technology.  for example, if client side has 10 html files from A.html to J.html, suppose A.html file is the one that contains the signalr client code, when A.html is opened, it connects to your signalr server, but when client moves to B.html or any other html, the connection ends immediately!

Comment: The idea is that a client will navigate to a url route with http get request and receive some json that they can do whatever they want with. We want however if they navigate to some url resource instead of receiving a response with json in its body we want them to be constantly in real time using signal r receiving data (probably in the same json form) that they can they parse with parse.json in jquery (or .net client or however). We will provide them the hub methods they should create in whatever client they choose.

Comment: then you can host the index.html or any php or aspx in your own Web Server, however, if the client close the browser or navigate to Another Web site, the connection stops immediately! and how can the client's own codes be interact with this html in real time?  then the problem goes back to the client needs to connect to your signalr Server with their own codes!

Answer (score 1):

*if they navigate to some url resource instead of receiving a response with json in its body we want them to be constantly in real time using signal r receiving data*

I don't think this is possible with SignalR. Reason is that all SignaR communication is done through single route (xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/signalR) + all SignaR connections are established using *handshake* (By client sending *negotiate* request to this route. Well maybe not all - not sure if negotiation is happening in case you initialize SignalR connection object with specific transport).